# Why can't all the mount point in root directory changed to /mnt/temporary & /mnt/removable?

Tags: filesystem, mountpoint

It seem a obsoleted in the root directory with all the mount point.
For example:

```
/cdrom
/media
/mnt
```

So, why can't it change to something like this:
New Hierarchy:

```
/mnt/temporary  #Can short it to /mnt/tmp
/mnt/removable  #Can short it to /mnt/rmb
```

Here's an excerpt from pathname.com for Filesystem Hierarchy.

[image]

Reference:
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is not clear if you are wanting to debate the FHS or if you want to configure custom mount points. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: I guess it's a form of debate but if it's possible to configure the hierarchy into appropriated mount points then thanks for the reference, I'll learn a bit more in fstab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FHS 3.0 specs](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/fhs/fhs/ch03s02.html) (currently in beta, part of LSB 5.0) don't list `/cdrom` now:

> The following directories, or symbolic links to directories, are required in /.
>
> ```
> Directory   Description
> bin         Essential command binaries
> boot        Static files of the boot loader
> dev         Device files
> etc         Host-specific system configuration
> lib         Essential shared libraries and kernel modules
> media       Mount point for removable media
> mnt         Mount point for mounting a filesystem temporarily
> opt         Add-on application software packages
> run         Data relevant to running processes
> sbin        Essential system binaries
> srv         Data for services provided by this system
> tmp         Temporary files
> usr         Secondary hierarchy
> var         Variable data
> ```

Discussion of the new standard takes place in the [LSB mailing lists](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/lsb-discuss). I recommend that your suggestion be posted there.

---

Considering your suggested mount points, and current default behaviour on modern desktop Linux distros, I think (`/media/tmp`) is a better option. Most systems I use now (Arch, Debain `jessie`, Ubuntu 14.04) mount drives on subdirectories in `/media/$USER/` (presumably due to the desktop environment I use (GNOME)). Note that this mounting doesn't really distinguish between removable media and others, since partitions on the local hard disk (on which Ubuntu was installed) still get mounted in `/media`, so `/media` is, for all intents and purposes, the top location for mounting disks.